# .click event not working

Tags: jquery, click

I'm trying to trigger a click event. But the event isn't doing anything.
We are using the following code. If we change `.click` for an `.addClass` everything works fine.

```
var deeplink = window.location.hash.substr(1);
if (deeplink.length < 20) {
    var dfilter = deeplink;
    jQuery("body").find('.esg-filterbutton').each(function () {
        var filter = jQuery(this);
        if (filter.data('fid') == dfilter) 
        filter.click();
    })
}
```

Comment: `filter.click()` is enough

Comment: @where is your click function code ,what it was return filter

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code

```
filter.trigger("click");
```

instead of

```
   filter.click(this);
```

Because [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) should be used to define function which need to be executed after click. And you are looking for triggering click event on the element.

**EDIT** - I think you are trying to bind click event to `filter` objects and trigger it then use below code

```
filter.click(function(){
   alert('click fired');
 }).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this still doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Do you have `.click(function(){..})` defined anywhere for this element? Are you trying to bind click event for filter object?

Comment: Actually, if no arguments are passed to `click`, then we need to execute `trigger('click')`.